# php count returns 1 instead of real array length

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array created using array_push that contains 2 elements and count() returns 1.
Why does it does that ?

code :

```
$length = count($usersNoList)
var_dump($usersNoList);
echo "Length:".$length;
```

output :

array(2) { [0]=> string(16) "Kenyon Velazquez" [1]=> string(12) "Seth Ellison" } Length:1

full code :

```
$usersNoList = array();
while($result = $rawResult -> fetch_assoc()) {
    $user = new Utilisateur($result['IdUtilisateur'], $co);
    // looks for the user in those who have lists
    if($key = array_search($user -> getId(), $usersWithList) == FALSE) {
        // construct the array of names
        array_push($usersNoList, $user -> getPrenom()." ".$user -> getNom());
    } else {
        // remove this value from the array
        var_dump($usersWithList);
        array_splice($usersWithList, $key - 1, $key);
        var_dump($usersWithList);
    }
}
if($length = count($usersNoList) > 0){
        echo "
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>Ces utilisateurs n'ont pas encore de liste : ";
        var_dump($usersNoList);
        echo "Length:".$length;
        for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
            echo $usersNoList[$i].", ";
        }
        echo $usersNoList[$length - 1].".";
        echo "</p>
            </td>
        </tr>";
        }
```

Comment: And what is your question? What are you trying to do, what did you try?

Comment: Works fine for me https://3v4l.org/ZhP3l

Comment: Works fine for me too on localhost and [here](https://3v4l.org/dSSUE)

Comment: You have a syntax error in this code.  So this is obviously not your exact code.  Please copy/paste instead of trying to re-write it by hand.

Comment: Where/how is `$length` defined? If the array is multidimensional that could be the behavior. https://3v4l.org/f1Tfq

Comment: added a more large code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$length` takes the value of the **boolean** expression `count($usersNoList) > 0`, which is true. This is why it evaluates to 1 (true).

Just declare and assign `$length` before the `if` statement to use it inside the statement and for the condition. E.i:

```
$length = count($userNoList);

if($length > 0) {

    var_dump($usersNoList);
    echo "Length:".$length; // displays 2
}
```

Comment: @Nonoreve you're welcome. If the problem is totally solved, please consider accepting the anwser so that the post displays as solved.

Answer (score 1):

@Jules answer has inspired me to think adding parentheses like

```
if(($length = count($usersNoList)) > 0){
echo $length;
```

}
would also work.